# Service launches, then crashes

Tags: android, service

Alright I got a good bit of help in my last question so instead of beat my head against the wall I have decided it would be better to post my code for my auto starter / service / manifest here and see what I can get.
It goes like this: Auto starter(Just fixed) --> Service --> Main activity

So I am not so much worried about the first and last steps as they are both taken care of. I just need to figure out how to get the auto starter to run the service which ties the main activity to the background. So the question: Why is it that when I run this it starts the app then promptly crashes it about 30 seconds later also why is the app not going to the background instead of staying up front?
here is the code:

```
package path.to.file;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class Monitor extends Service {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "::Monitor";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service created.");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("path.to.file.MainActivity");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service started.");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service destroyed.");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service bind.");
    return null;
}
}
```

As well as the updated manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
installlocation="internalOnly"
package="path.to.file"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="Monitor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="path.to.file.Monitor" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="autoBot" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the starter as requested:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class autoBot extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "StartAtBootServiceReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onReceive:");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Monitor.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, please post the logcat so we can see what is happening.

Comment: @Sam this is unfortunate because I am running this off of my phone and dont have access to log cat. give me about 20 minutes for the emu to boot up and I'll get back to you.

Comment: If your phone is tether to your computer and you run your app from Eclipse, then you will get logcat traces just the emulator.

Comment: @Sam What do you mean? Just pop the usb into the phone and run the app off my phone?

Comment: Correction here, after rebooting the phone it no longer stops after X amount of time however it does not run in the background as I am trying to get it to do.

Comment: Yes, you can run apps that you are developing on your phone. You can search for existing online tutorials to explain how to do this. As for running an Activity in the background, when an Activity is in the background you lose a lot of what makes an Activity an Activity, perhaps this background code belongs in your Service?

Comment: I know as I have been doing so for the last day with quite a bit of ease mind you. Right now I want to know what is going wrong with the code presented uptop that would cause it to stay forward and not in the back.

Comment: Your not really posting the part that starts the service up.  Please show us your Start Service.  Also the crash could be in the activity.  The only thing in the service that is capable of crashing from what I can see is i.setAction("path.to.file.MainActivity");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);

Comment: Also why .MainActivity but not .Monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Monitor to .Monitor in the manifest.

You should use startService() rather than startActivity().

Comment: Code, I added the requested code to the top of the page. I hope this helps out a bit more.

Comment: Ok. well I see you are using startActivity() If you are trying to start a service it should be startService(i) instead.

Comment: Monitor.class refers to your Service i believe.  so use startService() with intent directed to Monitor.class if on the other hand you are trying to start an activity you still need to use the right name MainActivity.class and not Monitor.class

Comment: Question, do I need a main activity anymore. The way I see it the auto starter acts as the main launcher thus I dont really need a "Launcher" in the manifest?